# Como leer atributos u Obtener Desde un Objeto en Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, magento2, knockoutjs

he estado todo el dia probando y testeando , para que me recorra el Objeto

Ok mi duda es la siguiente, he estado probando con este metodo

```js
var Person = function () {

this.pepa = ko.observableArray([{
  value:0, 
  name:"juan", 
  url:"juan.pdf"
},
{
  value:1, 
  name:"maria", 
  url:"maria.pdf" //quiero hacer un ciclo u obtener este elemento 
},
{
value:2,
name:"carlangas",
url:"carlangas.pdf"
}
]);
 
  
this.eName = ko.observable(this.pepa());

  this.select = function (element) {
    this.element = this.eName();
    console.log(element.eName().toString());
    //console.log(this.pepa([{name}]));
  }
};

ko.applyBindings(new Person());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<select height="3" data-bind="options: pepa, optionsText: 'name' , optionsValue: 'value', selectedOptions:eName, event:{ change: select}">
</select>
```

, he estado tratando de conseguir el valor del atributo pero nada asi que he tratado de recorrerlo desde el foreach que el tiene pero nada , que deberias aplicar para recorrerlo?? un for() ordinario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para obtener el valor que quieres necesitas accesar a la propiedad `pepa` usando el indice del elemento seleccionado.  Algo asi:

```js
var Person = function () {

this.pepa = ko.observableArray([{
  value:0, 
  name:"juan", 
  url:"juan.pdf"
},
{
  value:1, 
  name:"maria", 
  url:"maria.pdf" //quiero hacer un ciclo u obtener este elemento 
},
{
value:2,
name:"carlangas",
url:"carlangas.pdf"
}
]);
 
  
this.eName = ko.observable(this.pepa());

  this.select = function (element) {
    this.element = this.eName();
    console.log(element.eName().toString());
    console.log(this.pepa()[this.eName()].url);
  }
};

ko.applyBindings(new Person());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<select height="3" data-bind="options: pepa, optionsText: 'name' , optionsValue: 'value', selectedOptions:eName, event:{ change: select}">
</select>
```